# thinktecture identitymanager without identityserver3, is it possible?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identitymanager

Identity manager  work with an identity service like "asp.net-identity" without identityserver, or is it neccesary for implement a single sign-on system?

There is any example about that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that out. But according to below link, it is possible to use identity manager without identity server. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx

If you are to implement single sign-on you should use IdentityServer.